# read output of a command line by line into a vector of strings in c++

Tags: c++, linux

I need to read the output of a bash command into vector of strings line by line.I tried this code with ifstream but it gives error. What must i use to parse them instead of ifstream?

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  vector<string> text_file;
  string cmd = "ls";

  FILE* stream=popen(cmd.c_str(), "r");
  ifstream ifs( stream );

  string temp;
  while(getline(ifs, temp))
     text_file.push_back(temp);
  for (int i=0; i<text_file.size(); i++)
      cout<<text_file[i]<<endl;
}
```

Comment: It is not possible to use `ifstream` with a C library file stream. You will need to stick with C I/O and possibly convert its results to a `std::string`. What you **really** want is Boost.Filesystem.

Comment: @pmr What does Boost Filesystem have to do with pipes?

Comment: "it gives error" is not a very good problem description. Is it a compile-time error? A run time error? Is there some specific error message? Or do you get behavior different from what you expect?

Comment: @JamesKanze I assumed that the `ls` is actually what he is trying to achieve, but I could be wrong. Sorry.

Comment: @pmr Aha.  You may be right.  I didn't even look at the actual command (since the title spoke about the problem of capturing the output of another program).  I agree: Boost Filesystem, rather than a pipe from ls.  (For other commands: I used to have a `pipebuffer` class, with an `opipestream` and and `ipipestream` which used them, but I don't know if they're still lying around.  IMHO, that would be the way to go.)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use C I/O with the C++ iostream facilities. If you really want to use `popen`, you need to access its results with [read](http://linux.die.net/man/3/read).

If `ls` is really what you want to do, give
[Boost.Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm)
a try.

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  namespace bfs = boost::filesystem;
  bfs::directory_iterator it{bfs::path{"/tmp"}};
  for(bfs::directory_iterator it{bfs::path{"/tmp"}}; it != bfs::directory_iterator{}; ++it) { 
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you would like to use GNU library function [getline](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Line-Input.html)

```
int main ()
{
    vector<string> text_file;
    FILE *stream = popen ("ls", "r");
    char *ptr = NULL;
    size_t len;
    string str;

    while (getline (&ptr, &len, stream) != -1)
    {
        str = ptr;
        text_file.push_back (str);
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < text_file.size(); ++i)
        cout << text_file[i];
}
```